# Disable download option on HTML5 video layer in Slider Revolution

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, html5-video

I want to disable the download option for videos in my slider using Slider Revolution.

I can't find how I can make it, because I don't know, how to insert tag `ControlList="nodownload"` in this case.

Do you know how can I do it? Or some script? I want the other controls to stay visible.

Comment: If there is only one video on the screen/page then you can try `var my_video = document.querySelector("video");` to access your video tag. From there you can try `my_video.controlsList = "nodownload";`. Otherwise show code of an example of a basic page with slider (video).